# Voltage regulator keeps shorting and dying

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

[image: Schematic]

I am trying to investigate a problem with a voltage regulator I am using in my circuit. The regulator in question is the [ADP3339](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP3339.pdf) (3.3 V variant).

I have assembled a few boards using this regulator, however, some have failed. The regulator keeps shorting (the output is the same as the 6 V input instead of 3.3 V).

A problem with how I connected this regulator is on the PCB where I am soldering it on, I have put pin 4 (bigger output pin, there is another output pin on this package) as GND pin on the PCB. To try and get around this, I put some electrical tape on top of this pad and left this pin unsoldered as there is another output pin on this package. Is there a problem in doing this?

I have attached my schematic above (there are two regulators in my circuit, but I don't seem to be having problems with the 1.8 V variant. There is only one component that uses this supply, while everything else on the board (microcontroller, sensors, op-amps) uses the 3.3 V output from the 3.3 V regulator.

Comment: Before an intelligent answer can be given, we need more information. You should provide a link to the device data sheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP3339.pdf. From that, it shows that the thermal resistance with minimal 2 oz pads on all pins is 126C/W. With only one pin soldered, it may be in the order of 200C/W. If you can show a schematic with  input voltage and output load, we may be able to help.

Comment: How much current is going through the regulator? Is the part attached to a large ground area for heat sinking?

Comment: @qrk, ~10mA. I thought the large pin on the regulator is for ground for heat sinking but it is another OUT pin for the regulator. On my PCB this pad is conencted to ground via a polygon pour.

Comment: What voltage is Vin. At even 200C/W at 1O mA Vin of 49V or more SHOULD be OK.

Answer (score 2):

The large pin is for the heatsink connection, which is why the data sheet asks for a copper area of some size.

If you can't solder it to your board solder it to some other heatsink. perhaps solder to a bunch of copper wires that stick up into the air.